# Third party firmware for WPN824?

Tags: router, firmware, flashing

My router recently developed some sort of DHCP malfunction so I decided to flash the firmware.  And being the geek that I am I figured, while I'm flashing it, why not upgrade it?  However, finding a legitimate third party firmware seems to be more difficult than I originally thought.  DD-WRT and OpenWRT don't seem to support it and Tomato doesn't have anything saying one way or the other.  My router is a NetGear WPN824v3.  If anybody has any suggestions, they would be greatly appreciated.